# Knockout does not update UI when observableArray is a property of other model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have 2 observableArray connected to each other. When a "feature" is clicked, I try to show "tasks" of it. However KO, does not update UI when I clicked a feature. On the console, I can track my viewModel, and I can see tasks successfully loaded on selectedFeature. However, UI does not update, even all arrays are defined as observable.

Here is a live [demo on fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmet229/99tq5m6r/)

Please tell me where I am missing?

```
function GetFeatures() {
    var url = "/Project/GetFeatures";

    $.get(url, "", function (data) {
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
            projectVM.features.push(new featureViewModelCreator(item, projectVM.selectedFeature));
        });
    });

};

function GetTasks(selectedFeature) {
    var url = "/Task/GetTaskList";
    $.get(url, { "FeatureId": selectedFeature.FeatureId }, function (data) {

        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
            selectedFeature.tasks.push(new taskViewModelCreator(item, selectedFeature.selectedTask));
        });
    });
};

function taskViewModelCreator(data, selected) {
    var self = this;
    self.TaskId = data.TaskId;
    self.Title = data.Name;
    self.Status = data.Status.Name;
    self.CreatedDate = data.CreatedDate;
    self.UserCreatedFullName = data.UserCreated.FullName;

    this.IsSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return selected() === self;
    });
}

function featureViewModelCreator(data, selected) {
    var self = this;
    self.FeatureId = data.FeatureId;
    self.Name = data.Name;
    self.Status = data.Status.Name;
    self.CreatedDate = data.CreatedDate;
    self.UserCreatedFullName = data.UserCreated.FullName;

    self.tasks = ko.observableArray();

    this.IsSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return selected() === self;
    });

    self.selectedTask = ko.observable();
    self.taskClicked = function (clickedTask) {
        var selection = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.model.tasks(), function (item) {
            return clickedTask === item;
        })[0];
        self.selectedTask(selection);
    }
}

function projectViewModelCreator() {
    var self = this;
    self.ProjectId = 1;
    self.features = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedFeature = ko.observable();

    self.featureClicked = function (clickedFeature) {
        self.selectedFeature(clickedFeature);
        GetTasks(clickedFeature);
    }
}
var projectVM = new projectViewModelCreator();


ko.applyBindings(projectVM, $('.taskmanTable')[0]);

GetFeatures();
```

On the UI

```html
<div class="taskmanTable">
    <table class="table table-hover featureList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: features">
            <tr data-bind="click: $root.featureClicked, css: { active : IsSelected } ">
                <td><span data-bind="text: Name"> </span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-hover taskList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedFeature.tasks">
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Title"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct version with key notes: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/99tq5m6r/25/). KO documentation is quite a detailed one.

---

You have mentioned an interesting note about UI code style: "As I know, we don't use () on UI". I did not put attention to this fact before.

1. We can really omit brackets for an observable: [ko observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html);

View contains an observable with **no brackets**:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: displayMessage" /> Display message
</label>
```

Source code:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    displayMessage: ko.observable(false)
});
```

2. We can omit brackets for an observable array on UI: [ko observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

View contains: `<ul data-bind="foreach: people">`, while
View model has:

```
self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bert' },
        { name: 'Charles' },
        { name: 'Denise' }
    ]);
```

3. We can omit brackets on UI for 'leaf' observables or observables arrays. Here is your modified [code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/99tq5m6r/27/). `data-bind="if: selectedFeature"` and `data-bind="foreach: selectedFeature().tasks">` only leaf observable braces are omitted.
4. Finally, can we omit brackets for 'parent' observables? We can do it by adding [another ko UI-statement](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) (with instead of if, example 2).

> The with binding will dynamically add or remove descendant elements
> depending on whether the associated value is null/undefined or not

5. But, I believe, we can not omit brackets for parent nodes outside UI statement, because it is equal to a javascript statement: `projectVM.selectedfeature().tasks`. Othervise `projectVM.selectedfeature.tasks` will not work, because observables does not have such property tasks. Instead an observable contains an object with that property, which is retrieved by calling it via brackets (). There is, actually, an example on knockoutjs [introduction](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) page. `<button data-bind="enable: myItems().length < 5">Add</button>`

---

The code below uses the following fact (which can be found [here, example 2](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)):

> It’s important to understand that the if binding really is vital to
> make this code work properly. Without it, there would be an error when
> trying to evaluate capital.cityName in the context of “Mercury” where
> capital is null. In JavaScript, you’re not allowed to evaluate
> subproperties of null or undefined values.

```js
function GetFeatures() {
  var data = {
    Name: "Test Feature",
    FeatureId: 1
  }
  projectVM.features.push(new featureViewModelCreator(data, projectVM.selectedFeature));

};

function GetTasks(selectedFeature) {
  var data = {
      Title: "Test Feature",
      TaskId: 1
  }
  selectedFeature().tasks.push(new taskViewModelCreator(data, selectedFeature().selectedTask));
};

function taskViewModelCreator(data, selected) {
  var self = this;
  self.TaskId = data.TaskId;
  self.Title = data.Title;
  // Step 3: you can omit $root declaration, I have removed it
  // just to show that the example will work without $root as well.
  // But you can define the root prefix explicitly (declaring explicit
  // scope may help you when you models become more complicated).
  
  // Step 4: data-bind="if: selectedFeature() statement was added
  // to hide the table when it is not defined, this statement also
  // helps us to avoid 'undefined' error.
  
  // Step 5: if the object is defined, we should referense 
  // the observable array via -> () as well. This is the KnockoutJS
  // style we have to make several bugs of that kind in order
  // to use such syntax automatically.

  this.IsSelected = ko.computed(function() {
    return selected() === self;
  });
}

function featureViewModelCreator(data, selected) {
  var self = this;
  self.FeatureId = data.FeatureId;
  self.Name = data.Name;


  self.tasks = ko.observableArray();

  this.IsSelected = ko.computed(function() {
    return selected() === self;
  });

  self.selectedTask = ko.observable();
  
}

function projectViewModelCreator() {
  var self = this;
  self.ProjectId = 1;
  self.features = ko.observableArray();
  self.selectedFeature = ko.observable();

  self.featureClicked = function(clickedFeature) {
    self.selectedFeature(clickedFeature);
    GetTasks(self.selectedFeature);
  }
}

var projectVM = new projectViewModelCreator();

ko.applyBindings(projectVM, $('.taskmanTable')[0]);

GetFeatures();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taskmanTable">
  <table class="table table-hover featureList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: features">
      <tr data-bind="click: $root.featureClicked, css: { active : IsSelected } ">
        <td><span data-bind="text: Name"> </span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <table data-bind="if: selectedFeature()" class="table table-hover taskList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: selectedFeature().tasks()"><!-- $root -->
      <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: Title"></span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Spirit, thanks for reply. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmet229/99tq5m6r/) I add $root to my view, which is make sense. On the second part, I am not sure about clickedFeature. I am binding features which is loaded with featureViewModel. On the projectVM, "features" is defined as observableArray. When the view is clicked, "clickedFeature" is just the item of "features" which is loaded with models. Therefore it is a modal I think. Am I right? What kind of information do you need more?

Comment: @JustAnotherCodeLover, have you tried to change .Name property to .Title in taskViewModelCreator? This seems to me the root reason. And we should reference the observable array using () syntax in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Spirit. I've tried your fiddle and check my code. Step1 is my copy/paste fault, OK. Step2 has no problem on my code, because I returned Title from server.(For dummy data you are right). Step3 is optional as you said. Step4 is DEFINITELY the source of the problem. Step5 is has no affect on the UI. Using (), is just converting to JS array to KO Array. But on the VM, I changed featureClicked function line "GetTasks(clickedFeature)" and did not use "()" in GetTasks function. It works fine again.

Comment: On the UI, I changed data-bind from "foreach: selectedFeature().tasks()" to "foreach: selectedFeature.tasks". It says, code is fine, features loaded, but tasks not working (with no error). Then I erased "if: selectedFeature()" data-bind tag. With the "foreach: selectedFeature().tasks()" It throws error. When I change it to "foreach: selectedFeature.tasks", it does not throw error on console, but tasks could not be loaded. What is the main problem with "()" ? As I know, we don't use () on UI. I couldn't figure out.

Comment: @JustAnotherCodeLover, We can omit brackets on UI for 'leaf' observables or observables arrays, but we can not do it for chained observables. +1 you opened an interesting fact to me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers @Spirit. Now KO is much more clear for me :)